# Can't Paste Python Code without Breaking Indents

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I do have editor.formatOnPaste set to true but I get the most annoying bug whenever I copy paste any python code into vscode.

```
unexpected indentPython(parser-32)
```

It seems to fix itself if I backspace and re-indent but sometimes it doesnt and I have to retype the code...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try going to `Settings` -> `Text Editor` -> `Formatting` and uncheck `Editor: Format On Paste`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This was my problem! Opening files from another repo (not created locally) caused
indentation messup and I realized it was reverting to using tabs. Unchecked to fix.